# Positioning section and aside

Tags: html, css, position

Heyo, so I'm having a bit of hard time making aside and section to position correctly when making the screen smaller. What happens is the section drops below the aside when shrinking the screen. Here the pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxjbyg

Here's the code:

```
#container {
width:90%;
margin: 0 auto;
background:pink;
height:300px;
}
aside {
width:12%;
height:100px;
background:green;
border-radius:20px;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:20px;
}
section {
width:86%;
height:100px;
background:purple;
border-radius:20px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Change margin-right in section{} from 20px to 2%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `width:calc(86% - 20px);` one the section to take on consideration  the `margin-right` that you used on `aside` which is `20px;`

```css
#container {
  width:90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:pink;
  height:300px;
}
aside {
  width:12%;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
  border-radius:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:20px;
}
section {
  width:calc(86% - 20px);
  height:100px;
  background:purple;
  border-radius:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <aside>ASIDE</aside>
  <section>SECTION</section>
</div>
```

Comment: @BenasLengvinas margin-right has fixed width which make it not included in the percentage value and could make the whole percentage (aside + section + margin ) go over 100%, and that what causes the section to break

Comment: I figured out one other way of doing this (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxjbyg). Which solution would you say is better?

Comment: @BenasLengvinas https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyBdQW ... now if you want the space between aside and section to be fixed then you should use `calc()` function like my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here `margin-right: 20px;` of aside inturn causes the overall width to increase above 100%. Reduce this to `margin-right: 15px;` which will solve the issue.